# Game Freezes - Running a Powerup for X seconds

Tags: java, android

I am making a game where there are powerups the user can press. When the user presses a powerup, I want the powerup to run for 3 seconds and then all affected variables will return to normal. I tried the following code below (focusing on the speed images fall down the screen faster than normal for 3 seconds):

```
if (x2 >= power_remove_X && x2 < (power_remove_X + power_remove.getWidth())
                    && y2 >= power_remove_Y && y2 < (power_remove_Y + power_remove.getHeight())) {
      //image tapped
                power_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //Find out which power up and apply the effect
                Log.d("GameScreen", "Power 3 Selected");
                power_comparer(PowersScreen3.getDecodedChoice());
            }

private void power_comparer(Image decodedChoice) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long refresh = power_start + 3000;

 if (decodedChoice == Assets.powerup_speedup) {         
        Log.d("Powerup - Refresh", Long.toString(refresh));
        while (currentTime < refresh) {
            PowerConstants.popcorn_speed = 4;
            PowerConstants.popcorn_color_speed = 10;
            PowerConstants.popcorn_mad_speed = 4;
            speeduptapped = true;
            //Log.d("Powerups", "all popcorn speed up");
        }
```

However, this code causes my game to freeze when I press the powerup. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your game is gonna stop everything else while your while loop is executing. It is best to set a variable that states the current powerup. Then, on each update, check to see if the effect has worn off.

Comment: Ok but how can I set up a timing system so that each powerup can run for a certain amount of time? I got the effects to work, they just stay permanent as I am not sure how to change them back after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Do the exact same thing you are doing now. Record the start time of the effect. Then, on each update, compare it to the current system time. If the time elapsed is greater than the duration, remove the effect.

Comment: Maybe as simple as replacing "while" with "if" ?..
But perhaps separate thread with all the checks running through the independent logic will be actually better.